# Is a chess set with full figured human pieces permissible to own?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, games-toys, art

[Link to a similar chess set](http://www.italfama.it/eng/details.php?o=&&id_prodotto=847)

Is a chess set with full figured human pieces permissible to own?
 My question is due to the second commandment.

Comment: @user11408 There is no character limit to your post. Go ahead and [edit] in what "the second commandment" is, and which parts of it you think may apply to this situation that led you to have this question. The more explict you can be about your concerns the better we are able to address them. Don't forget as well that things which may seem obvious to you aren't always obvious to others. Best to clarify explicitly what you think and what you seek.